# How to use PhpMyAdmin to import/export from/to the server it runs on?

Tags: export, import

When I choose to import/export a data script with PhpMyAdmin, it offers me to upload/download a file with my browser from/to my PC where I access it from. But I'd like to load/save the file from/to the file system of the server where the MySQL server and PhpMyAdmin run. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set a directory to import files from in the phpMyAdmin config file...

From the docs https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#web-server-upload-save-import-directories

$cfg['UploadDir'] string
    The name of the directory where SQL files have been uploaded by other means than phpMyAdmin (for example, ftp). Those files are available under a drop-down box when you click the database or table name, then the Import tab.

Comment: the link is: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#web-server-upload-save-import-directories